# What is the difference between 'WDI' and 'wbstats' package in R?

Tags: r, package, data-science, data-analysis

What is the difference between 'WDI' and 'wbstats' package in R?

Many thanks.

Comment: They are written by different authors.  In addition `wbstats` says `programmatic access to data and statistics`, while `WDI`'s description is `Search, extract and format data`.  Both are APIs.  To understand more, you may have to look into each function and check the behavior, output etc.  It seems to be a broad question.  What do you expect as a solution

Comment: Thanks, @akrun I want to analyse the data from World Bank, justing wondering which one I should use.

Comment: try both and check which one fits for your analysis.  I haven't tried those so can't give my input